# Insert markers to a string matching a pattern irrespective of case in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I am doing a search functionality where I want to highlight the matched pattern. SO, irrespective of the cases, I have to prepend and append all the patterns in the string with a `<$>` and `</$>` respectively.

```
highlight("RajkumarrAjkumarRAjkumaraj", "Ra") 
# should return "<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>rA</$>jkumar<$>RA</$>jkuma<$>ra</$>j"

highlight("RajkumarrAjkumarRAjkumaraj", "ra") 
# should return "<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>rA</$>jkumar<$>RA</$>jkuma<$>ra</$>j"

highlight("RajkumarrAjkumarRAjkumaraj", "rA") 
# should return "<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>rA</$>jkumar<$>RA</$>jkuma<$>ra</$>j"

highlight("RajkumarrAjkumarRAjkumaraj", "RA") 
# should return "<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>rA</$>jkumar<$>RA</$>jkuma<$>ra</$>j"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
> "RajkumarrAjkumarRAjkumaraj".gsub(/(ra)/i, '<$>\1</$>')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String#gsub()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub).

```
def highlight(str, pattern)

    str.gsub(/(#{Regexp.escape(pattern)})/i, "<$>$1</$>")

end
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But, in the ouput string all the occurrences are modified in the case of the pattern.

highlight("RajkumarrAjkumarRAjkumaraj", "Ra") gave me "<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>Ra</$>jkuma<$>Ra</$>j". 

But, I want it as "<$>Ra</$>jkumar<$>rA</$>jkumar<$>RA</$>jkuma<$>ra</$>j"

Comment: @Virtual Apologies, fixing that now.

Comment: How about replacing `$1` with `#{pattern}`?

Comment: @WayneConrad That will turn any mixed case into the replacement case, won't it?